# progress 4gl: how link two database with foreign key relationship

Tags: progress-4gl

How to link two databases in progress 4gl with foreign key relationship?

```
FOR EACH jeld-wen.customer :
    FIND FIRST adm2.order WHERE adm2.order.custnum = jeld-wen.customer.custnum NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
    IF AVAIL adm2.order THEN
    DISP jeld-wen.customer.custnum adm2.order.custnum adm2.order.ordernum.
END
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in there?

Comment: I really cant see what your asking but the general way of accessing a field in a specific database is: <dbname>.<tablename>.<fieldname>. So if one db is named adm1 and one adm2 you can to adm1.order.custnum and adm2.order.custnum (given there is a table in both with the field custnum).

Answer (score 1):

Progress has no "foreign key" support like you might find in some SQL databases.  Relationships are maintained by application code similar to what you have shown.

Rule #1 - Progress is not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a question in here although I assume you would not get the expected result from the query you have run.
The best thing you could do is refer the Data Dictionary for indexes and table relations it would give you a clear idea about the design of the Database and how are they related. In there you would find the relationship quite similar to 'foreign key relationship' in SQL if there is any.

Example Pregress DB:

```
           Member Table         Event Table
>          memberid             eventid
>          memberstatus         memberid
>          memberpayno          eventstatus
```

If you consider above example, memberid would be the foreign key equivalent in SQL.